# Use external yml config file for app inside kubernetes pod

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes pod which is based on spring boot. Locally I can start jar file with external file with this commands:

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=file:///Users/home/config/application.yml
```

But how to do it in kubernetes? I use Helm charts for configuration. Is there some solution with helm charts configuration?

I tried this:

default `application.yml`

```
init:
  message: "Test message loaded from default application.yml file"
spring:
  config:
    location: ${CONFIG_LOCATION}
```

`application-mockup-configuration.yml` insight helm chart:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: application-mockup-configuration
data:
  application-mockup-configuration.yml: |
    init:
      message: "Test message loaded from default external application-mockup-configuration.yml file !!!!!!!!!!!"
    spring:
      application:
        name: mockup-test
      jackson:
        default-property-inclusion: non_null
      jmx:
        enabled: false
```

deoloyment.yaml from helm chart:

```
  envFrom:
  - secretRef:
      name: mockup-secret-env
  - configMapRef:
      name: application-mockup-configuration-configmap-env
  env:
    - name: CONFIG_LOCATION
      value: "/home/config/application-mockup-configuration.yml"
  volumeMounts:
    - name: application-mockup-configuration
      mountPath: /home/config/application-mockup-configuration.yml
      subPath: application-mockup-configuration.yml
```

But I the issue is that I always get the default message from the default `application.yml` file insight the test spring boot app. External file is not overriding the value for `init: message.....` Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Example https://kubebyexample.com/learning-paths/developing-spring-boot-kubernetes/lesson-4-deploying-spring-boot-kubernetes-3

Comment: I mean you reference the mock config only in the default config.

Comment: yes. I get the message into the default config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Locally, I can start jar file with external file with that command: `java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=file:///Users/home/config/application.yml`.  But how to do it in kubernetes?".

In a Kubernetes environment..., you would *not* directly execute the `java -jar` command as you do on your local machine.
Instead, this command would be defined in the Dockerfile for your application's Docker image, or in the container spec in your [`Deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

The command to start your application would typically look like this:

```
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Then in your Kubernetes `Deployment`, you would add an additional argument `--spring.config.location=file:/home/config/application.yml`:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-app
    image: your-image-repo/your-image-name:tag
    args: ["--spring.config.location=file:/home/config/application.yml"]
    volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /home/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
        items:
        - key: application.yml
          path: application.yml
```

In that configuration, the `args` field adds the `--spring.config.location=file:/home/config/application.yml` argument to the command that starts your application. When your application starts up, it reads its configuration from the `application.yml` file that was loaded from the [`ConfigMap`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume).

Once you have applied the [Helm chart](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/) with `helm install` or `helm upgrade`, Kubernetes will take care of starting your application with the specified command and arguments.

When the pod starts, the Spring Boot application will run with the provided argument, pointing the configuration location to the file mounted from the `ConfigMap`.

---

So, in details, in your `configmap.yaml`, define the configuration you want to provide to your application:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  application.yml: |
    init:
      message: "Test message loaded from external application.yml file"
    spring:
      application:
        name: mockup-test
      jackson:
        default-property-inclusion: non_null
      jmx:
        enabled: false
```

Then, in your `deployment.yaml`, define a Deployment object that mounts the ConfigMap as a volume, and add the `--spring.config.location` argument to the container spec:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: your-image-repo/your-image-name:tag
        command: ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
        args: ["--spring.config.location=file:/home/config/application.yml"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /home/config
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
          items:
          - key: application.yml
            path: application.yml
```

That setup assumes that the `app.jar` file is located at the root of your Docker image. If it is in a different location, you would need to update the `command` accordingly. Similarly, replace `your-image-repo/your-image-name:tag` with the path to your actual Docker image.

When you deploy this Helm chart with a command like `helm install my-release ./my-chart`, Helm will create a Kubernetes Deployment and ConfigMap according to these templates.
The `Deployment` will start your Spring Boot application with the specified command and arguments, which will tell the application to load its configuration from the external `application.yml` file provided by the `ConfigMap`.